# Server crashes after ~20 minutes

Tags: crash

My Ubuntu 20.04 server crashes around 20 minutes after boot. It is as if the server is turned off.

There is nothing in the log files, and no kernel panic on screen when it crashes.

RAM passes 24 hour RAM test with no errors.

If I install another OS it does not crash.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some systems `systemd` will suspend the computer even when it is not idle. I believe `systemd` looks at keyboard and mouse interaction - not whether the CPUs are firing on all cylinders. If you are not sitting at the server, it will kick in after boot - even if you use it intensely via `ssh`.

The reason you do not see anything in the log might be that the log entry about suspending is not flushed to disk. It would have been flushed to disk if you resumed the machine. But if you instead turn it off, this log information is lost.

So you are probably not seeing a crash, but instead a server that is suspended-to-ram.

Change `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` to:

```
[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=no
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=no
```